# Как задать кастомное называние для foreign key поля?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть две таблицы

```
class Request
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string Fio { get; set; }
    public string Otdel { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MTR> Mtrs{ get; set; }
}

class MTR
{
    public int MtrId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request{ get; set; } 
}

public class HardwareContext : DbContext
{
    public HardwareContext() : base("HardwareContext")
    { }
    public DbSet<Request> Requests{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<MTR> Mtrs{ get; set; }
}
```

При генерации EF задает кривые названия для ключей, например:

```
FK_dbo.MTRs_dbo.Requests_Request_RequestId
PK_dbo.MTRs
```

Как сделать кастомные названия для этих полей? Я хочу изменить разделитель c`.` на `_`. Напрмиер `PK_dbo_MTRs`

Comment: [Атрибут `Column`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: это не то......

Comment: Вы пробовали и не сработало?

Answer (score 1):

Ключевое слово здесь Fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasMany(r => r.Mtrs)
        .WithOne(m => m.Request)
        .HasConstraintName("MyFKConstraint");
}
```

Comment: Ругается на WithOne - Ошибка CS1061 'ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<Request, MTR>" не содержит определения для "WithOne" и не удалось найти метод расширения "WithOne", принимающий тип "ManyNavigationPropertyConfiguration<Request, MTR>" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).